# how to center a fontawesome icon and span

Tags: css, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

I have this markup. I need to center align (horizontal and vertical) both the `<i>` and `<span>` that are next to each other. please guide.

```
<span (click)="onGoBackClick($event)" class="cursor-click">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x"></i>
  <span>Go back to previous page</span>
</span>
```

Comment: you could use flex-box .... something like this: .parent{display:flex;align-items:center;} and put some justify-content property bases on your needs, i assume that you will need center or space-around

Comment: vertical-align ? unless something floats ... both are standing on the baseline, reset it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to center this, flexbox is a good solution:

```
.cursor-click {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; // center horizontally
    align-items: center; // center vertically
}
```

Demo here: https://codepen.io/aureliendebord/pen/VNOGZz

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox solution:

```
.cursor-click {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Vertical align solution:

```
.cursor-click i, 
.cursor-click span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```